# Jackson - generic getValue method

Tags: java, json, jackson

All subclasses of `ValueNode` in Jackson (the JSON library) have different methods for getting the underlying value object e.g. `IntNode` has `getIntValue`, `BooleanNode` has `getBooleanValue` and so on.

Why is there no generic/polymorphic method called simply `getValue` which just returns an `Object` and where that `Object` is either `Integer` or `Boolean`, etc., based on the type of the node the method is called on?

Or ... is there such a method actually?
I need such a method for my purposes but seems the library designers did not find that adding such a method would be useful. Or ... is that method missing on purpose, for some reason?

My purpose: In the code below I am traversing the tree and generating a structure composed only of `HashMap`, `Object[]` and Java basic types (like `Integer`, `Boolean`, etc.). If I had such a method, instead of all these ***if-else if-else if*** blocks, I would have just one single method call (in the case when the `JsonNode` is a leaf node i.e. a sub-type of `ValueNode`). But I don't have such a method in Jackson, it seems. So I had to code all those ugly ***if-else if-else if*** blocks.

CODE:

```
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        private static Object traverse(JsonNode nd) {
            if (nd instanceof ObjectNode) {
                ObjectNode ndd = (ObjectNode) nd;
                HashMap mp = new HashMap();
                Iterator<String> it = ndd.getFieldNames();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    String s = it.next();
                    mp.put(s, traverse(ndd.get(s)));
                }
                return mp;
            } else if (nd instanceof ArrayNode) {
                ArrayNode ndd = (ArrayNode) nd;
                Object[] arr = new Object[ndd.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < ndd.size(); i++) {
                    arr[i] = traverse(ndd.get(i));
                }
                return arr;
            } else if (nd instanceof NullNode) {
                // NullNode ndd = (NullNode)nd;
                return null;
            } else if (nd instanceof BooleanNode) {
                BooleanNode ndd = (BooleanNode) nd;
                return ndd.getBooleanValue();
            } else if (nd instanceof IntNode) {
                IntNode ndd = (IntNode) nd;
                return ndd.getIntValue();
            } else if (nd instanceof LongNode) {
                LongNode ndd = (LongNode) nd;
                return ndd.getLongValue();
            } else if (nd instanceof DoubleNode) {
                DoubleNode ndd = (DoubleNode) nd;
                return ndd.getDoubleValue();
            } else if (nd instanceof DecimalNode) {
                DecimalNode ndd = (DecimalNode) nd;
                return ndd.getDecimalValue();
            } else if (nd instanceof BigIntegerNode) {
                BigIntegerNode ndd = (BigIntegerNode) nd;
                return ndd.getBigIntegerValue();
            } else if (nd instanceof TextNode) {
                TextNode ndd = (TextNode) nd;
                return ndd.getTextValue();
            }

            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed while traversing the JSON tree at node: ||| " + nd.asText() + " |||");
        }
```

Comment: _I need such a method for my purposes_ Discuss those purposes. `JsonNode` and its subtypes are meant to represent a JSON tree, therefore the abstractions represent JSON types, not Java types.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis "therefore the abstractions represent JSON types, not Java types" well, yeah but the JSON types are mapped to Java types after all, OK, will explain my purposes a bit better.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are returning an `Object` you can use something like this

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
return mapper.convertValue(nd,Object.class);
```

For this particular test cases it worked

```
        JsonNode nodeBool = BooleanNode.TRUE;
        Object objectBool = mapper.convertValue(nodeBool,Object.class);
        Boolean returnValBool = (Boolean) objectBool;
        System.err.println(returnValBool);

        JsonNode nodeDouble = new DoubleNode(3.4);
        Object objectDouble =    mapper.convertValue(nodeDouble,Object.class);
        Double returnValDouble = (Double) objectDouble;
        System.err.println(returnValDouble);
```

and it outputed as expected:

```
true
3.4
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good. But are you sure it will preserve the semantics of my code? I mean, is this giving me the internal value in whatever type it had before e.g. if it was Boolean, will it stay Boolean?

Comment: Made a small test before posting and it worked. I can not guarantee all use cases, but some small unit test for the method should determine this

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem :)

I am not sure why there is no generic method. I believe it might have something to do with the fact that they deal with not only object types? well, I am not really qualified to justify their design decision, however I can help you with your generic method.

You are right, you can't just call value(), but you can just call serialize(..,..)

More detail:

All value nodes hold their own value. All value nodes know how to be serialised. We can take advantage of this.

**NOTE: This will be slightly hacky**

You can write your own serialiser and have it store your values to retrieve them:

```
public static class MyGen extends GeneratorBase {

        protected MyGen(int features, ObjectCodec codec) {
            super(features, codec);
        }

        private Object currentObject = null;

        @Override
        public void flush() throws IOException {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        protected void _releaseBuffers() {
            // do nothing           
        }

        @Override
        protected void _verifyValueWrite(String typeMsg) throws IOException {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void writeStartArray() throws IOException {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void writeEndArray() throws IOException {
        }           // do nothing

        @Override
        public void writeStartObject() throws IOException {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void writeEndObject() throws IOException {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void writeFieldName(String name) throws IOException {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void writeString(String text) throws IOException {
            currentObject = text;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeString(char[] text, int offset, int len) throws IOException {
            currentObject = new String(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeRawUTF8String(byte[] text, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
            currentObject = new String(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeUTF8String(byte[] text, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
            currentObject = new String(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeRaw(String text) throws IOException {
            currentObject = new String(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeRaw(String text, int offset, int len) throws IOException {
            currentObject = new String(text);           
        }

        @Override
        public void writeRaw(char[] text, int offset, int len) throws IOException {
            currentObject = new String(text);           
        }

        @Override
        public void writeRaw(char c) throws IOException {
            currentObject = new Character(c);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeBinary(Base64Variant bv, byte[] data, int offset, int len) throws IOException {
            currentObject = bv;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeNumber(int v) throws IOException {
            currentObject = new Integer(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeNumber(long v) throws IOException {
            currentObject = new Long(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeNumber(BigInteger v) throws IOException {
            currentObject = v;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeNumber(double v) throws IOException {
            currentObject = new Double(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeNumber(float v) throws IOException {
            currentObject = new Float(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeNumber(BigDecimal v) throws IOException {
            currentObject = v;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeNumber(String encodedValue) throws IOException {
            currentObject = encodedValue;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeBoolean(boolean state) throws IOException {
            currentObject = new Boolean(state);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeNull() throws IOException {
            currentObject = null;
        }

    }
```

Note, this is a prototype just-for-fun test and probably should be done with some more thought.

But with that, I can do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
        MyGen gen = new MyGen(0, new ObjectMapper());


        String test = "{ \"a\" : \"test\", \"b\" : 1, \"c\" : true, \"d\" : 2.5 }";

        JsonNode tree = new ObjectMapper().readTree(test);

        Impl instance = new DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl();

        ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();

        for(JsonNode node : tree) {
            node.serialize(gen, instance);
            Object currentObject = gen.currentObject;
            System.out.println(currentObject);
        }

    }
```

Which prints:

```
test
1
true
2.5
```

Hope that helps :)

Artur

Ps: The other answer is much shorter and better - but I thought this is cool too, so I'll post it anyway

Edit:

With regards to one of your comments. The generator will retrieve the original value and it will be up to you to preserve what that value is. You will have full control over that.

Comment: Thanks but... come on, you can't be serious... let's send it to the moon and back rather. Why not? :) Still... thanks for trying to find a solution.

Comment: haha - no I agree this is not an ideal solution. The objectmapper is much better. But well .. it works and if you're desperate, it's .. umm .. something :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I've extended the `StdDeseralizer` and created an EnhancedDeserializer.
During the deserialization when `deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)` is called, I simply store the `objectMapper = (ObjectMapper) jsonParser.getCodec()`. Because it is actually the `ObjectMapper` instance.
After that, I'm able to call the `objectMapper.convertValueMethod` which does the work.

```
public abstract class EnhancedDeserializer<T> extends StdDeserializer<T> {

protected ObjectMapper objectMapper;

public EnhancedDeserializer(final Class<?> clazz) {
    super(clazz);
}

@Override
public T deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
    objectMapper = (ObjectMapper) jsonParser.getCodec(); // trick! the codec is the ObjectMapper
    return deserialize(objectMapper.readTree(jsonParser));
}

public abstract T deserialize(JsonNode node);

public <E> E readAs(JsonNode node, Class<E> clazz) {
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return objectMapper.convertValue(node, clazz);
}

public <E> E readAs(JsonNode node, String key, Class<E> clazz) {
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return readAs(node.get(key), clazz);
}

public <E> E readAs(JsonNode node, TypeReference<E> typeReference) {
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return objectMapper.convertValue(node, typeReference);
}

public <E> E readAs(JsonNode node, String key, TypeReference<E> typeReference) {
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return readAs(node.get(key), typeReference);
}
```

}

To prove that I have a simple object.

```
public class MyObject {

    private Object fieldObject;

    private Long fieldLong;

    private String fieldString;

    private Map<String, Object> fieldWithGeneric;

    // getters setters omitted
}
```

The deserializer code by using the `EnhancedDeserializer` is really simple:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

import java.util.Map;

public class MyObjectDeserializer extends EnhancedDeserializer<MyObject> {

    public MyObjectDeserializer() {
        super(MyObject.class);
    }

    @Override
    public MyObject deserialize(JsonNode node) {
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

        myObject.setFieldObject(readAs(node, "obj", Object.class));
        myObject.setFieldLong(readAs(node, "lng", Long.class));
        myObject.setFieldString(readAs(node, "str", String.class));
        myObject.setFieldWithGeneric(readAs(node, "map", new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
        }));

        return myObject;
    }
}
```

And finally the tests:

```
public class MyObjectDeserializerTest {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(new SimpleModule()
                        .addDeserializer(MyObject.class, new MyObjectDeserializer()));
    }

    @Test
    public void deserialize_ObjectField_Integer() throws IOException {
        final MyObject myObject = objectMapper.readValue(aSimpleJsonField("obj", "1"), MyObject.class);
        assertThat(myObject.getFieldObject(), is(1));
    }

    @Test
    public void deserialize_ObjectField_String() throws IOException {
        final MyObject myObject = objectMapper.readValue(aSimpleJsonField("obj", "\"my-string\""), MyObject.class);
        assertThat(myObject.getFieldObject(), is("my-string"));
    }

    @Test
    public void deserialize_ObjectField_Double() throws IOException {
        final MyObject myObject = objectMapper.readValue(aSimpleJsonField("obj", "123.456"), MyObject.class);
        assertThat(myObject.getFieldObject(), is(123.456));
    }

    @Test
    public void deserialize_LongField() throws IOException {
        final MyObject myObject = objectMapper.readValue(aSimpleJsonField("lng", "456789123456789"), MyObject.class);
        assertThat(myObject.getFieldLong(), is(456789123456789L));
    }

    @Test
    public void deserialize_StringField() throws IOException {
        final MyObject myObject = objectMapper.readValue(aSimpleJsonField("str", "\"hello world\""), MyObject.class);
        assertThat(myObject.getFieldString(), is("hello world"));
    }

    @Test
    public void deserialize_genericField() throws IOException {
        final ObjectNode root = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
        final ObjectNode genericNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
        genericNode.put("str_0", "string");
        genericNode.put("int_1", 123);
        genericNode.put("long_2", 123456789123456L);
        genericNode.put("double_3", 987.654);
        genericNode.put("bool_4", true);
        root.set("map", genericNode);

        final MyObject myObject = objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(root), MyObject.class);

        final Map<String, Object> map = myObject.getFieldWithGeneric();
        assertThat(map, notNullValue());
        assertThat(map.get("str_0"), is("string"));
        assertThat(map.get("int_1"), is(123));
        assertThat(map.get("long_2"), is(123456789123456L));
        assertThat(map.get("double_3"), is(987.654));
        assertThat(map.get("bool_4"), is(true));
    }

    private String aSimpleJsonField(String key, String value) {
        return "{ \"" + key + "\" : " + value + " }";
    }
}
```

By having the `EnhancedDeserializer` in place your code is going to be really simple and what is more important type-safe. You can now drop the `raw` `unchecked` suppressions.

I hope it helps.